# iTunes 11 - View Selected Songs' Playtime

Tags: itunes

After upgrading to iTunes, I can't seem to find a way to know how much time the selected songs take to play. This used to be at the bottom of every window of iTunes.
The only way I can find this now, is in the playlists, shown as for example 29 songs, 1.2 hours.

Any way to get the old bar at the bottom back?

Answer (score 3):

Click **View → Show Status Bar**, or use the ⌘/ keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Neither the total playtime nor the "View --> Show Status Bar" are available in iTunes 11.1.1.

Comment: @SabreWolfy I just double checked, and I still have the Show Status Bar option and key shortcut available, on iTunes 11.1.1, on Mountain Lion (10.8). Are you running Windows perhaps? It might be a different menu in that case.

Comment: Yes, Windows XP. Can't find such a menu entry. The status bar is shown though. However, the total play length for the selected podcasts is only shown in "List" view, not "My Playlists".